# GAP field of values of an irreducible character

Tags: representation-theory, characters, gap

Given a group $G$ in GAP, a character $\chi$ in $Irr(G)$ and a field $F$ how can I compute $F(\chi):=F(\chi(g)|g\in G)$?

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward:

> G:=SmallGroup(60,5);
> chi:=Irr(G)[2];
> F:=CF(7);
> Field(F,chi);

Comment: Why do you start with ˋCF(7)ˋ ?

Comment: For the sake of an example (I did not intend to be meaningful).